# Can embedded Tomcat to load Servlet 3.0 annotaitons from Eclipse classpath?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7, servlet-3.0

I have an app that's entirely configured by annotation - no web.xml - that I want to run in embedded Tomcat from Eclipse.

I can find lots of examples that rely on specifying a `WEB-INF/classes` dir, but I would rather run it entirely from the Eclipse classpath.

Here is my launcher:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setPort(8080);

    tomcat.setBaseDir("<work dir>");
    Context ctx = tomcat.addWebapp("/myapp", "<app base>");
    StandardJarScanner scan = (StandardJarScanner) ctx.getJarScanner();
    scan.setScanClassPath(true);
    scan.setScanBootstrapClassPath(false); // just guessing here

    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getServer().await();

}
```

The app starts up - I can get the static content, but the annotation-configured elements are not picked up.

I'm using the `tomcat-7-embed` distribution.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669507

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedded tomcat 7 servlet 3.0 annotations not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669507/embedded-tomcat-7-servlet-3-0-annotations-not-working)