# loading tomcat using code

Tags: java, tomcat

im using tomcat 7 , and im trying to do something nice.
i want to have a little swing program to operate my current project (a site)

i wish to have in that swing application a button to run the server , shut the server and such.

i know there is the option of running it as soon as i start the application but i dont want it. i want to have the option to click a swing button and load it.

for that , i need to run the server by code.

is there a way to load tomcat server via code?

Comment: execute tomcat catalina.bat from program through runtime and cmd.exe

Comment: yes. Search for Process/ProcessBuilder on google and modify accordingly.

Comment: Tomcat actually has an API to boot it directly from Java code so you don't have to fiddle with spawning processes. See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669507/embedded-tomcat-7-servlet-3-0-annotations-not-working

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution for this may be Using `RunTime` you can do this -

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("startup.bat");`

similarly, to stop -

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shutdown.bat");
```

Assuming both batch files exist in tomcat bin directory.

Comment: Actually i was looking for an tomcat API (im pretty sure theres a solution there) but this is a great easy answer. thank you.