# Tomcat 8.0.20: The requested resource is not available using @WebServlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, annotations

When I bing Servlet to url using web.xml like it's shown below everyting works fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>lv.rtu.sux.laip.web.MainServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But when I'm trying to do this using @annotation @WebServlet I receive this message:  **The requested resource is not available using**.

I've tried two variants:

```
@WebServlet(name="hello",urlPatterns={"/hello"})
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet{

@WebServlet("/hello")
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet{
```

**UPDATE**
I've tried to run this app using normal Tomcat (before this I was using Embedded Tomcat) and now it works fine.
But how can I normally run it with Embedded Tomcat? I am using libraries from maven group **org.apache.tomcat.embed**:

```
    String webappDirLocation = "src/main/webapp/";
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

    tomcat.setPort(8089);
    Context ctx = tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());
    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getServer().await();
```

Do I have to do some additional actions to make this app work with annotations?

Comment: And did you remove the web.xml file from the deployed application? Because it declares that the app version is 2.5, and this version doesn't support annotations.

Comment: Yes, I removed the web.xml

Comment: I found the soultion. It's described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669507/embedded-tomcat-7-servlet-3-0-annotations-not-working