# Tomcat Catalina context - add existing servlet to context

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, annotations, catalina

I would like to add an existing servlet to a context and it works, when I use (Main.java):

```
Tomcat.addServlet(ctx, "MyServlet", new MyServlet());
ctx.addServletMappingDecoded("/url_pattern", "MyServlet")
```

However, I have annotations inside servlet to map url_pattern(MyServlet.java):

```
@WebServlet(name = "MyServlet", urlPatterns = { "/url_pattern" })
@MultipartConfig(
  fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024 * 1, // 1 MB
  maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10,      // 10 MB
  maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 100   // 100 MB
)
```

Unfortunately, these annotations do not work. I would like to delete mapping from Main.java and use mapping from my Servlet annotation.

I use Tomcat 10.0.0.

**Main.java**

```
import java.io.File;

import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LifecycleException,
    InterruptedException {
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setPort(8082);

    Context ctx = tomcat.addContext("", new File(".").getAbsolutePath());

    Tomcat.addServlet(ctx, "MyServlet", new MyServlet());
    
    ctx.setAllowCasualMultipartParsing(true);
    ctx.addServletMappingDecoded("/url_pattern", "MyServlet");
    
    
    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getConnector();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use Servlet 5.0 classes and annotations (`jakarta.*`) or Servlet 4.0 classes (`javax.*`)? Tomcat 10 is a Servlet 5.0 container.

Comment: I use jakarta.servlet 5.0 and jakarta.annotaion 2.0 (it is the newest version as far as I know). Tomcat does not see Servlet mapping inside web.xml as well.

Comment: I would like to add also, that these annotations work, when I run tomcat server from eclipse, but when I use Main class (embedded tomcat), these annotations are not working.

Comment: Can you add the content of your `Main` class to your question? Do you call the [`Tomcat.addWebapp`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Tomcat.html#addWebapp-org.apache.catalina.Host-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method, which performs the usual context initialization and annotation scanning?

Comment: I hava edited my question with Main class content. I do not call Tomcat.addWebapp, I will read the documentation once again and check addWebapp method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embedded tomcat 7 servlet 3.0 annotations not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669507/embedded-tomcat-7-servlet-3-0-annotations-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind embedded Tomcat is to do in code, what the usual Tomcat does through configuration. Therefore the configuration of servlets through annotations is not as straightforward as it is in Tomcat.

You'll be facing two problems:

#### Annotation scanning

The main difference between [`Tomcat#addContext`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Tomcat.html#addContext-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and [`Tomcat#addWebapp`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Tomcat.html#addWebapp-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) is that the latter adds some default `web.xml` (the `jsp` and `default` servlet) and scans for Servlet 3.0 annotations and `ServletContainerInitializer`s.

If you don't need or don't want the default `web.xml` configuration, you can obtain the same thing with:

```java
Context ctx = tomcat.addContext("", new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
ctx.addLifecycleListener(new ContextConfig());
```

#### Resources

Even after enabling annotation scanning Tomcat will not find your servlets, because it looks under `/WEB-INF/classes` of your `docBase` (which you set to be the current folder). This is a probably empty folder. If you want Tomcat to scan also the classes in your application you'll need to:

1. Find the JAR file or directory that contains your `Main` class,
2. Mount the contents of that JAR to the `/WEB-INF/classes` (virtual) folder of your application (cf. [Tomcat resources](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/resources.html)):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws LifecycleException, InterruptedException {
   ...
   // Add the JAR/folder containing this class to PreResources
   final WebResourceRoot root = new StandardRoot(ctx);
   final URL url = findClassLocation(Main.class);
   root.createWebResourceSet(ResourceSetType.PRE, "/WEB-INF/classes", url, "/");
   ctx.setResources(root);
   ...
}

/*
 * Tries to find the URL of the JAR or directory containing {@code clazz}.
 */
private static URL findClassLocation(Class< ? > clazz) {
    return clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
}
```

#### Summary

At the end you'll end up with:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LifecycleException {
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setPort(8082);
        final Context ctx = tomcat.addContext("", Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().toString());
        // Add the standard ContextConfig, which scans for annotations
        ctx.addLifecycleListener(new ContextConfig());
        // Add the JAR/folder containing this class to PreResources
        final WebResourceRoot root = new StandardRoot(ctx);
        final URL url = findClassLocation(Main.class);
        root.createWebResourceSet(ResourceSetType.PRE, "/WEB-INF/classes", url, "/");
        ctx.setResources(root);
        // Run Tomcat
        tomcat.getConnector();
        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
```

Comment: That is right, sometimes reading documentation once again is a good idea!